# Nativescript: deploying a release to google-play gives warnings about unused, obfuscated and native native-code

Tags: android, google-play, nativescript, google-play-console

I'm getting said errors in the Google Play console when I upload a new apk:

- This App Bundle contains Java / Kotlin code, which can be
  deobfuscated. We recommend uploading a deobfuscation file so that
  your crashes and ANRs can be more easily analyzed and resolved
- This App Bundle contains native code and you have not uploaded any
  debugging symbols. We recommend uploading a symbol file so that your
  crashes and ANRs can be more easily analyzed and resolved.

It seems like the first one can be fixed by adding `minifyEnabled true` to this part of the build.gradle file:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

The second one should be fixe by adding:

```
ndk { debugSymbolLevel 'FULL' }
```

But when I add this to the gradle-file, I get an error when building the app:

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. No signature of method:
> build_1ermujkr3n2a9bpd0mitv774.android() is applicable for argument
> types: (build_1ermujkr3n2a9bpd0mitv774$_run_closure10) values:
> [build_1ermujkr3n2a9bpd0mitv774$_run_closure10@4a4868e2]

Furthermore, Google complains about the file size (unused code) and recommends (actually, demands) that I should use an App Bundle.
I found something on the web how to create one, but I have no idea how to do this with nativescript...

Anybody here with experience with the symbolLevel and app-bundles?

As a sidenote: It's interesting that Google shows these as warnings and not as errors and yet, you can't release the apk without fixing them. Shouldn't it be my call to decide if that warning actually matters to me or not?

Comment: How to create the app bundle: https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tooling/publishing/android-app-bundle

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a ton!!!

Comment: did you fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the app.gradle file, not the build.gradle. The build.gradle will be generated by Nativescript when you build the application.